# How can I combine 2 projects in Android Studio Without Errors

Tags: android-studio

I have two android projects. One is the login and membership screen and the other is my main project. I did both separately, in case it would be okay to combine them later, but I realized that I made a big mistake. When I tried to combine the two, it started giving errors all the time and I couldn't do it. Gradle files were probably missing, but I'm very confused. Can anyone help me how to do it easily?

Error:(1, 0) Plugin with id 'kotlin-android-extensions' not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no easy option to "combine" two projects like to merge them without exceptions. But you can do the following:

1. The easiest way to combine two projects is to take the smaller project and copy all the files in `/java` `/layout` `/drawable` to the other project.
2. Then I would look up all files in `/values` and copy the values if you changed them.
3. After that you should look at the `Mainfest` and see wether you made changes there and transfer them. This will make most of the errors not come up because you just copied all the classes.
4. If you get the error anyway then go to your gradle files (`build.gradle` for project and module and `settings.gradle` if you use android studio bumblebee or newer) and check if there is any plugin or line you have in one project and not in the other and then add that accordingly.